# No Exception message in my catalina.out

Tags: java, exception

I am using spring controller to get the values from tables.

If data is not there in table for some id's, I couldn't get any exception in catalina.out file. I am generating a WAR and placed in webapps folder of tomcat7.

I would like to show an error page while getting no datas for id's. Now it went to default error page. I need to show other error page which says "There is no record for this Id" for this.

Can anyone give a hint in this?

Here is class,

```
    @Controller
    public class GenerateController extends AbstractController
    {
      @Resource
      private UserService userService;

      @Resource
      private LoanService loanService;

      @Resource
      private GroupService groupService;

      protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception
      {
        String groupID = request.getParameter("groupId");
        Integer conv = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(groupID));

        Group group = this.loanService.getGroupById(conv.intValue());
        GroupLoan groupLoan = this.groupService.getGroupLoanByLoanId(
          ((Loan)group.getLoans().get(0)).getId().longValue());
        LoanDTO loan = this.loanService.getLoanById(groupLoan.getLoanId().longValue());
        GroupDTO groupDto = this.groupService.getGroupById(loan.getGroupLoan().getGroupId().longValue());


        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        return modelAndView;
      }
    }
```

Comment: need to post some code, controller/jsp

Comment: answer posted, should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways you can achieve this,

1.) From `Controller` itself, `return a view`

```
String message = "There is no record for this Id" +id;

return new ModelAndView("myPage", "message", message);
```

where `myPage` can be your error page.

2.) From `Controller` , throw some custom exception, say `GroupNotFoundException`.

Please refer [this](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for detailed explanation.

Comment: @Mary.Hansen yes , you can use `if else` block based on data null or not, and set the view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your method your saying throws Exception.It is throwing a generic exception.May be you can throw a more specific exception